# FBSDK MessengerSharer connection error

Tags: objective-c, share, facebook-messenger

I just create a new App in developers.facebook.com to try to share an image from my App to Messenger.
To be sure that my App integration was working fine i've done the classic login test as suggested in official guide and all working well.
Always following guide i added :

```
if ([FBSDKMessengerSharer messengerPlatformCapabilities] & FBSDKMessengerPlatformCapabilityImage) 
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Foto del 30-04-14 alle 19.44.jpg"];
    [FBSDKMessengerSharer shareImage:image withOptions:nil];
}
```

to share simple image imported in my project.
The result is that messenger is opened with the exact image preview but when I try to share it with a contact I get the following error messagge:

> there was a problem connecting to messenger . check your connection
>   and try again

Actually you think that might be a connection problem or something is missing in the project?
I tried to find something similar on the web but no results .Thanks for your time

Alex